# Django: tie two redirects to a single Update button depending on where the user came from

Tags: python, django, redirect

So, i have a rather usual "update item" page that is a class-based view which inherits UpdateView. (in views.py it looks like "class ItemUpdateView(UpdateView) and it has method get_success_url(self) defined which contains the redirect url where user will be taken after clicking "Update" button.
My problem is that in my application, there are two different pages that could lead me to this "Update item" page, and depending on the page that user comes from - i want to take the user **back** to either pageA or pageB upon the successful update of the item.
I wasn't able to find the best-practices of how to handle this anywhere on the web, so - would really appreciate the help.
My guess is that I need to create an additional parameter that will be a part of the url and will contain A or B depending on the pageA or pageB that user came from, i.e. the url itself would be something like '/itemUpdate/int:pk/sourcepage' => '/itemUpdate/45/A'. Does that sound like a correct aproach or is there a better way?

Comment: Your approach seems fine.  If you're having trouble implementing it, add your code.

Comment: Hi Anya, did you solve the problem?

Comment: @eisa-nahardani Unfortunately not, i am still struggling with it. What if I had function-based view instead? would it still be possible to use request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')?

Comment: of course it is possible but class-based view is not difficult, can you tell me new error?we are nearing the end of the answer!

Comment: it is better that you share your view and form in addition to error.

Comment: @eisa-nahardani I implemented everything exactly as you suggested in your updated code, but now - when I click "update" button and expect that form_valid() will be called -  nothing actually happens. I can see that when I click "Update" - get_initial(self) gets called - so the table is not updated and redirect does not happen. What could i be missing?

Comment: i should inspect your code. probably you are using GET method when you click on update button. please edit question and add template and views.py completely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way that you can check `Meta` dictionary in request:

write in your `views` file:

```
class ItemUpdateView(UpdateView):
    previous_url = ''
    form_class = UpdateItem

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.previous_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        print(self.previous_url) 
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
       initial = super().get_initial()
       initial['success_url'] = self.previous_url
       return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
       self.success_url = form.cleaned_data['success_url'] 
       print(self.success_url)
       return super().form_valid(form)

  # also you can use get_success_url instead of form_valid()
  # def get_success_url(self):
  #   return super().get_form().cleaned_data['success_url']
```

and then write a `hidden field` in your form and name it `success_url`

```
class UpdateItem(forms.ModelForm):
    success_url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    
    class Meta:
       model=Item
       fields=['itemName','quantity']
```

**Note** you can not use `instance` in order to get `success_url` field, because this field belong to form nor your model instance !

refer to [documentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

Comment: Thanks so much @eisa nahardani  I have just tried adding the line you suggested into my "def get_success_url(self)" and simply printing out "previous_url", but discovered that it contains the url of the Update_Item page, while i was hoping it would instead contain the previous page (that is a page that redirected the user to Update_Item page.) So, to clarify - this is tied to submit-button on Update-Item page. Any ideas of what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: tagging you here so that you would see it @eisa-nahardani  Thank you in advance!

Comment: you  dont should write it in get_success_url(self), because it reset url- i will update my answer soon

Comment: Again, thank you so much! I am trying to get this to work, but getting "type-error" - get_initial() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  - it points to line " return super().get(request, *args, kwargs)"...

Comment: I am still new to django, so - am a bit confused. I was able to get both get and get_initial to work, but in my get_success_url i am getting an error. :(
I am indeed using the modelform in forms.py . It looks like this:

class UpdateItem(ModelForm):

 success_url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
 class Meta:

Comment: Apologies, my comment got cut off.
class Meta:
   model=Item
  fields=['itemName','quantity','success_url']

It now gives me the error in get_success_url() that says "'dict' object has no attribute 'success_url'. What could i be doing wrong? Thanks again!

'dict' object has no attribute 'source_url'

Comment: My answer is updated, likely problem is instance, plz check it